# C++ Bubble Sorting and Selection Sorting

Tags: c++

Here's the problem.

Write a program that uses two identical arrays of at least 20 integers. It should call a function that uses the bubble sort algorithm to sort one of the arrays in ascending order. The function should keep a count of the number of exchanges it makes. The program then should call a function that uses the selection sort algorithm to sort the other array. It should also keep count of the number of exchanges it makes. Display these values on the screen.
Here's where my problem is. I can do void `bubbleSort` and void `selectionSort` and sort 20 random numbers that I input but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to add a counter for the number of exchanges in each of the sorting methods.

Also, the instruction says to use `int bubbleSort(long [], int);` and `int selectionSort(long [], int);`. I'm confused why I would be using int instead of void. Perhaps I use both?

Anyways, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

edit: Here's what I have so far.

```
//Sorting Benchmarks
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void sortArray (int [], int);
void showArray (const int [], int);
int bubbleSort(long [], int);
int selectionSort(long [], int);

int main()
{
    // Define an array with unsorted value
    const int SIZE = 20;
    int values[SIZE]{20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);

    // Display the values
    cout << "The unsorted values are:\n";
    showArray(values, SIZE);

    //Sort the values. 
    sortArray(values, SIZE);

    //Display them again.
    cout << "The sorted values are:\n";
    showArray(values, SIZE);

    return 0;
}

void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
     bool swap;
     int temp;

     do
     {
         swap = false;
         for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
         {
             if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
             {
                              temp = array[count];
                              array[count] = array[count + 1];
                              array[count + 1] = temp;
                              swap = true;
                              count++
                              dispCount()
                              }
                              }
                              } while (swap);
                              }

void dispCount()
{
     cout << "The current number of exchanges are " << count << endl;
}

void showArray(const int array[], int size)
{
     for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
         cout << array[count] << " ";
         cout << endl;

         system("PAUSE");
         }
```

With this, I'm getting a million errors, the biggest one being in int main, where it says expected primary-expression before "int" and expected ';' before "int". I've checked and I feel all the ;'s are where they belong.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me. All I'm looking for is some guidance on how to approach my problem with the counter.

Comment: Exactly ... Provide some code or google it yourself

Comment: I've already googled it extensively. As I said in my original post, I can do the first half of it. I can do the bubble sort and the selection sort. I just don't have a clue on how to do incorporate a counter to count each time it does an exchange, which is why I signed up here.

Comment: @user2745212 I hope my answer will atleast give u an idea to insert a variable and count your no.of swaps ..

Comment: @user1145009 Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for. Here's what I have so far but when I'm compiling, I'm getting an error that says "In function int main(), expected primary-expression before int"? 
//Sorting Benchmarks
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
// Function Prototypes
void sortArray (int [], int);
void showArray (const int [], int);
int bubbleSort(long [], int);
int selectionSort(long [], int);

int main()
{
    // Define an array with unsorted value
    int values[20]{20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);

Comment: I'm also hesitant to use printf because when I asked my professor for help, he told me to use 
{
temp = a[count];
....
a[count + 1] = temp;
ix++;
exchanges++;
}

I've never even come across the printf so I don't really feel comfortable using it. I would rather use stuff similar to the examples in my book.

Comment: Are you using Linux...???

Comment: No I'm not using Linux.

Comment: Is this windows..??? What IDE you are using for your C code compilation

Comment: This is windows. I'm using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void sortArray (int [ ], int ) ;
void showArray (int [ ], int ) ;
int count = 0;

int main ()
{
const int SIZE = 6;
int values[SIZE] = {7, 2, 3, 8, 9, 1} ;

cout << "The unsorted values are: \n";
showArray (values, SIZE) ;

sortArray (values, SIZE) ;

cout<< "The sorted values are: \n" ;
showArray (values, SIZE) ;

return 0;
}

void sortArray (int array [ ], int SIZE)
{
int temp;
bool swap;

do
{ swap = false;
for (int count = 0 ; count < (size - 1 ) ; count ++)
{
if (array [count] > array [count + 1] )
{
temp = array [count] ;
array [count] = array [count + 1] ;
array [count + 1] = temp ;
swap = true ;
count++;
dispCount();
}
}
} while (swap) ;
}

void dispCount(){
cout << "The current amount of swaps is " << count << endl;
}

void showArray (int array [ ], int size)
{
for (int count = 0 ; count < size ; count ++)
cout << array [count] << " " ;
cout << endl ;
}
```

Reference Links

[**Link 1**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/227402-help-finding-number-of-swaps-and-comparisons-of-sorting-algorithm/)

[**Link 2**](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/64-sorting-an-array-using-selection-sort/)

**[Link 3](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110604121845AA3nqR3)**

Answer (score 0):

```
static int count = 0; in the head of function bubbleSort;
```

put the `count++` after the code where you switch 2 numbers.

```
printf("%d", count); in the end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## The C Code I've written for you returns this output

You have provided this data 
    1   2   3   4   5   9   8   7   6
    11  12

`Selection sort` on this array took **14** swap operation

`Bubble sort` on this array took **48** swap operation

---

You are asking for a `counter` variable that holds the number of swapping operations in bubble sort as well as in your selection sort program.

I've written a **`C`** code for your both problems.

## Bubble sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 20
int Arr[size],i,j,counter=0;    
void bubble();
int main()
{
    printf("Enter your elements now\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d",&Arr[i]);
    printf("You have provided\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("\t%d",Arr[i]);
    printf("\nPress any key to perform Bubble sort\n");
    bubble();
    printf("Result after Bubble sort\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("\t%d",Arr[i]);
    printf("Bubble sort on this array took %d swap operation",counter);
    return 0;
}
void bubble()
{

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<(size-1)-i;j++)
        {
            if(Arr[j]>Arr[j+1])
            {
                Arr[j] = Arr[j] + Arr[j+1];
                Arr[j+1] = Arr[j] - Arr[j+1];
                Arr[j] = Arr[j] - Arr[j+1];
                counter++;
            }
            printf("\r");
        }
    }
}
```

## Selection sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 20
void selection();
int findmin(int []);
int i,j,Arr[size],min,counter;
int main()
{
    printf(" Enter your elements now \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%d",&Arr[i]);
    printf("You have provided this data \n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("\t%d",Arr[i]);
    printf("\nPress any key to perform selection sort\n");
    selection();
    printf("Result after selection sort\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        printf("\t%d",Arr[i]);
    printf("Selection sort on this array took %d swap operation",counter);
}
void selection()
{
    for(i=0;i<(size-1);i++)
    {
        j = findmin(Arr);
        if(Arr[i]>Arr[j])
        {   
            Arr[i] = Arr[i] + Arr[j];
            Arr[j] = Arr[i] - Arr[j];
            Arr[i] = Arr[i] - Arr[j];
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
int findmin(int a[])
{
    min = i;
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
    {   
        if(a[j]<a[min])
            min = j;
    }   
    return(min);
}
```